# Give focus to application control when application loses focus

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke

I have an application which is designed to run full screen constantly. This works fine normally, however, when things run in the background, for example, an antivirus update this can bring that window above my app. Thats fine because I can use things like:

- SetForegroundWindow
- ShowWindow
- SwitchToThisWindow

All of which allow me to bring my application back to the front. However, inside the application is a hidden text box which when the application loads is focussed. When I use one of the pInvoke calls above whilst the application is brought back to front, the focus is still on the existing application.

I am currently struggling with the best way of giving focus back to the control.

I could use Control.FromHandle but seems fairly complicated to get the controls I need and offer focus if  a specific tab page is at the front. Is there a better way, any thoughts / ideas welcome.

Comment: How about selecting that control just AFTER calling any of the mentioned methods? For example: `ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW) : targetControl.Select()` or `targetControl.Focus`. Also, you can make a use of the `Form.Activated` event.

Comment: You might be able to get the hWnd of the control you want focused and use: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setfocus

Comment: ["do not play walls and ladders with Raymond"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253)

Comment: Whatever the hidden textbox is doing for you (processing key presses from a barcode scanner perhaps?) you might be able to do another way (have the form read the key events, use a serial scanner instead of a keyboard wedge one) that is "less hacky". pps by hidden you surely mean "outside the visible area of the form" rather than "visible = false", right?

Comment: Thanks everyone, will give it a shot and come back with the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running this on a Windows 10 LTSB unit and as previously mentioned SetForegroundWindow and Show functions were not working along with many other functions I found on pInvoke. I managed to select the correct process and bring it to the forefront if something else takes its place to the top. The issue was that it would never activate no matter what I tried.

In the end, I implemented the following code which checks every 5 seconds, if my app is not the foremost and not maximised then minimise / maximise the window and this reactivates and refocuses the app:

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

    Public Declare Function ShowWindowAsync Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As IntPtr

    Private Declare Function GetWindowPlacement Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpwndpl As WINDOWPLACEMENT) As Boolean

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As IntPtr

    <Serializable>
    Friend Structure WINDOWPLACEMENT
        Public length As Integer
        Public flags As Integer
        Public showCmd As ShowWindowCommands
        Public ptMinPosition As System.Drawing.Point
        Public ptMaxPosition As System.Drawing.Point
        Public rcNormalPosition As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    End Structure

    Friend Enum ShowWindowCommands
        Hide = 0
        Normal = 1
        Minimized = 2
        Maximized = 3
    End Enum

    Private Async Function CheckCurrentApp() As Task

        Try

            ' Try and locate the core process
            Dim coreHandle = FindWindow(Nothing, "Name of window")
            If coreHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
                ' Can't find the core. Exit here.
                Exit Try
            End If

            ' Get information about the Core window
            Dim currentWindowInfo As WINDOWPLACEMENT
            GetWindowPlacement(coreHandle, currentWindowInfo)

            ' If the core is not the foreground window or isn't maximised then send a minimise (6) and maximise (3) request.
            ' Activate functions in user32 don't work - I spent a day trying to make it so. I could get the foreground window as the core but the input would 
            ' remain in a different application.
            If coreHandle <> GetForegroundWindow() OrElse currentWindowInfo.showCmd <> ShowWindowCommands.Maximized Then
                ShowWindowAsync(coreHandle, 6)
                ShowWindowAsync(coreHandle, 3)
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' DO SOMETHING WITH THE EXCEPTION.
        End Try

        Await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
        Await CheckCurrentApp()
    End Function
```